# H2ORandomForestEstimator with min_samples_split?

Tags: random-forest, h2o

What is the analogue of 
[`min_samples_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)
for [`H2ORandomForestEstimator`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#h2o.estimators.random_forest.H2ORandomForestEstimator) and [`H2OGradientBoostingEstimator`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#H2OGradientBoostingEstimator)?

(h2o `min_rows` == sklearn `min_samples_leaf`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the closest thing to min_samples_split is `min_split_improvement`: *Minimum relative improvement in squared error reduction for a split to happen*

Comment: Yes, thanks, [I surmised as much](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53656780/850781) ;-)