# Avoiding overfitting with H2OGradientBoostingEstimator

Tags: cross-validation, h2o

It appears that the difference between cross-validation and training AUC ROC with [`H2OGradientBoostingEstimator`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#H2OGradientBoostingEstimator) remains high despite my best attempts using [`min_split_improvement`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm-faq/splitting.html).

Using the same data with [`GradientBoostingClassifier(min_samples_split=10)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) results in no overfitting, but [I can find no analogue of `min_samples_split`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53642304/850781).

## Prepare Data

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=40,
                           n_clusters_per_class=10,
                           n_informative=25,
                           random_state=12, shuffle=False)

features = ["x%02d" % (i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=features)
df["y"] = y
nfolds = 5

import h2o
h2o.init()

h2of = h2o.H2OFrame(df)
h2of["y"] = h2of["y"].asfactor()
```

## Run modeling

```
def print_h2o_auc(m):
    print("{m} train: {a:.2%} xv: {x:.2%}".format(
        m=m.model_id, a=m.auc(), x=float(m.cross_validation_metrics_summary().as_data_frame().set_index("").loc["auc","mean"])))

from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator

for msi in [0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1]:
    m = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(
        model_id="gbm %g" % (msi),
        ntrees=100, max_depth=3, min_rows=100, min_split_improvement=msi,
        nfolds=5, fold_assignment="stratified",
        keep_cross_validation_predictions=True, seed=1)
    m.train(x=features, y="y", training_frame=h2of)
    print_h2o_auc(m)
```

Prints

```
gbm 1e-05 train: 84.35% xv: 77.12%
gbm 0.0001 train: 84.35% xv: 77.12%
gbm 0.001 train: 82.71% xv: 76.53%
gbm 0.01 train: 68.06% xv: 65.49%
gbm 0.1 train: 50.00% xv: 50.00%
```

IOW, the difference in performance remains significant (even though it does decline).

What else can I try to reduce overfitting?

Comment: for high-level tuning gbm guidelines I generally recommend this notebook: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/tutorials/gbm/gbmTuning.ipynb. Have you already taken a look at it?

Comment: As a side note it's not necessarily bad that you are seeing a difference between train and valid, the GBM could just be overfitting to your training dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min_split_improvment` is only one of the factors you can play with. If I were you, I would have used `GridSearch` with a small range of factors for

1. `ntrees`
2. `learn_rate`
3. `sample_rate`
4. `col_sample_rate_per_tree`

All of them are important to avoid over-fitting.